# Adding CSS border-bottom via JQuery on a table cell with colspan

Tags: jquery, css

I'm doing a little manipulation via JQuery to add a bottom border to a few cells.  However, for some reason a bottom border is also being added to a cell where it doesn't exist in JS code or CSS.  You can see via the image below and the jsfiddle code.  Might it be caused because of it's colspan?  http://jsfiddle.net/hCAwm/3/

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's because of the colspan that you applied with your jQuery earlier: [see my updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chippper/hCAwm/13/).

I don't know why you were adding the colspan, so I can't offer a fix - I'm just verifying the problem.